# URL could not be liked because it's been blocked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am developer of `www.iloveskola.lv` and I have created facebook login with API.
After user logs in with his facebook account he has opportunity to participate in voting game.

One question, 4 answers.
Each answer is facebook LIKE button.

When user press like button, LIKE content on facebook has been created automatically.
First 2-3 days its was working perfect, but now when user press button iframe content just blinks and nothing.

I checked this with mozilla(bug zilla) and saw following response:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"success":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"Invalid url","full":"URL could not be liked because it's been blocked.","errorUri":"\/connect\/connect_to_node_error.php?title=Invalid+url&body=URL+could+not+be+liked+because+it\u002527s+been+blocked.&hash=AQAh-oNvuhmlqYzH"}}}
```

For deep investigation you can try this system by yourself.
If our site is blocked want to hear explanation why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Like buttons as a voting mechanism in a promotion (which is expressly against Facebook policy) it's quite likely users were marking the resulting stories as spam, removing the Like shortly afterwards, hiding it from their news feed, etc.

When you try to share a link and it fails, there's a link in the error message for contacting Facebook if you believe the block is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your site has been blocked, most likely because they deemed to be spam or breaking their terms of service regarding your contest rules.  Contact their [developer group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) to find out how to get it unblocked.