# Opengraph meta tag og:type set to "product" errors (like button & URL linter/debug)

Tags: html, tags, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We recently noticed our facebook like buttons stop working. To investigate i ran the URL thru Facebook's Debugger (old URL Lint) tool and it gave me this error :

```
Object Type Not Allowed:    
Object at URL 'https://savingstar.com/coupons/boursin-cheese/4edfd63fec0f2532eb000106' of type 'og_products:product' is invalid because it the specified fb:app_id '111777372238952' is not the owner of specified og:type.
```

I am suspected this has something to do with the new Open Graph Beta types some how but i can't seem to find any evidence for this.  My suspicion is that i need to remove the `fb:app_id` in favor of `fb:admins`, but would love to hear if any one else has run into this issue and resolved it.

Example URL where we are currently seeing this :
https://savingstar.com/coupons/boursin-cheese/4edfd63fec0f2532eb000106

Here is a slightly edited version of the relevant meta tags as the Facebook URL **scraper** seeing it (using the link in the debugger tool) :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="grocery,coupon,coupons,ecoupon,ecoupons,grocery coupons,food coupons,groceries coupons,coupons for food" name="keywords">
<meta content="Get our exclusive Boursin Cheese coupon - expires 1/4/2012." name="description">
<meta content="Boursin Cheese Coupon" name="title">
<meta content="Buy ANY ONE (1) variety of Boursin Cheese, Save $1.00" property="og:title">
<meta content="product" property="og:type">
<meta content="https://savingstar.com/coupons/boursin-cheese/4edfd63fec0f2532eb000106" property="og:url">
<meta content="https://static1.savingstar.com/images/dyn/1897.png" property="og:image">
<meta content="SavingStar" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="Save big $$ on your groceries with SavingStar eCoupons. Nothing to clip. Nothing to print." property="og:description">
<meta content="111777372238952" property="fb:app_id">
```

As you can see i am setting the `og:type` to `product` as stated in the facebook like-button documentation here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

**UPDATE 2011-12-14 :** looks like my issue is most likely related to a reported and confirmed bug here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285421101492706

I'll update this when i have confirmed this is the root cause of my issue.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there is no `og:type` for "product" if you look at the official [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/#types) page. There's no discussion of it in the official Google Group but there is [one question](https://www.facebook.com/groups/opengraph/302773513080823/) out on the Facebook Group.

You'll either need to [specify your own](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/simpletypes/) namespace and type or use one of the [built-ins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/builtin/).

Comment: interesting, did facebook then decide to abandon its own [open graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types) and only support the official open graph protocol spec ?

Comment: The 2010 documentation will still work for Like buttons
The debug tool is validating against the (currently beta) 2011 Open Graph APIs announced at F8 - there's an open bug report in the platform bug tracker about this - the error message shown shouldn't prevent you using type:product with a simple page

Comment: Thanks Igy. I now understand that the Debug Tool error is not directly related to the Facebook Like button issue i am having.

Comment: It looks like Facebook has realized the error of its ways and amended the og:type specification. I went to the Object Debugger yesterday and it shows "og:type" = "og_products:product" where my OG metadata just lists "product" as the "og:type." Go figure.

Answer (score 3):

The value should be `og:product`

```
<meta property="og:type" content="og:product" />
```

Read more on it hear https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product/

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem and I found out how to better debug this sort of issue.

If you look at the POST request going back to Facebook when you click the Like button, the response is a JSONP error message:

```
{ "__ar" : 1,
  "jscc" : "",
  "payload" : { "error_info" : { "brief" : "Invalid url",
          "errorUri" : "/connect/connect_to_node_error.php?title=Invalid+url&body=URL+could+not+be+liked+because+it%27s+been+blocked.&hash=AQDCjOHl9oNv8d5P",
          "full" : "URL could not be liked because it's been blocked."
        },
      "show_error" : true,
      "success" : false
    }
}
```

There's a SO question about this with [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201395/url-could-not-be-liked-because-its-been-blocked).

Comment: Thanks. i saw that question but there doesn't seem to be any clear course of action to figure why the URL is blocked.  I tried posting to the [Facebook Developers group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) and received no response. I will try posting again.

Answer (score 0):

in the end i had to file a "bug" with facebook and someone there was able to at the least "unblock" the likes.
however, now we get the "Confirm" link showing up after you "like" something.
its progress.

not sure why filing a "bug" is the approach to get the URLs unblocked.

thanks for everyone's help on this !

Answer (score 0):

use this `<meta property="og:type" content="product.group">`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but according to [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product/):

> og:type: The value should be og:product